# Can I modify the printed stack trace when a Java program fails?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, stack-trace

I'm using IntelliJ idea, and everytime my program crashes when I'm doing test runs during the programming process I'm tired of seeing so many lines from the stacktrace, I just want to see a couple lines that tell me where my program failed or perhaps a dialog box. Is there any way I can achieve this in idea or Java in general? Thanks

Comment: Catch the exception and handle it yourself.

Comment: It's not a specific exception, I'm referring to the failures I'm getting when I'm writing the program and doing test runs, sorry if this wasn't clear.

Comment: Same basic difference. Just catch all the exceptions (i.e. `catch (Exception e) {...}`) in your `main()`.

Comment: `I just want to see a couple lines that tell me where my program failed` and exactly how should the JVM know which lines to show to you?

Comment: @millimoose What about runtime exceptions? What about exceptions on different threads?

Comment: If you use a logging framework and log the exception you can decide how many frames to show.

Comment: @ppeterka What about them? Just cross that bridge when you get to it. (With, say, [`setUncaughtExceptionHandler()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler))) Also, `catch (Exception)` will catch `RuntimeExceptions` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code prints only the first 5 lines of the stack trace of any Error or Exception that appears in the `doStuff()` method.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
        doStuff();
    }
    catch(Throwable t){
        StackTraceElement[] elements = t.getStackTrace();
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            System.err.println(elements[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awsome, works great, Thanks! Just one small correction, I believe the getStackTraceElements() should simply be getStackTrace().

Comment: @JavaMonkey22 You were right, I didn't test the code. Corrected now.

Answer (score 3):

You can maybe create your custom exception by extending the Exception you want for the specific behavior of your application. Then you can overwrite the method "setStackTrace", you can convert the stacktrace you get from an existing exception into a parameter that will be send to your new Exception class, you can thene xtract what you want from the existing stacktrace and modify it with the content you want.

```
class CustomException extends Exception {
        @Override
        public void setStackTrace(StackTraceElement[] stackTrace) {
            // Get elements I want from my stack trace
                    // Then I add what I want from the existing stacktrace and add some custom content
        }
    }
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should take a look at IntelliJ's [console folding customization](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/07/console-folding-customization/), which will only fold 'noisy' parts of your stacktrace. You will still be able to see the whole stacktrace if needed (for example when you are trying to see who called your methods).

Comment: This is also a good answer, thanks. It works I just can't get it the way I want it.