# Try-catch printing stack trace

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, try-catch

I'm coding a Java project using Eclipse.

I have a method which throws a custom exception if a file is formatted the wrong way and it should be caught by a "parent" method and handled silently (by moving the file to an "error" folder).

The problem is that, even though I use a try-catch block, the exception gets caught and handled but its stack trace is printed anyway, in red, on the console (even with an empty catch block).

The same problem also occurs with built-in exception.

I suspect this is caused by some Eclipse settings (something like "always print exception messages"), but I couldn't find anything on the Web.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            MyClass object = new MyClass();
            object.foo();   //exception thrown
        } catch(SaphanaException e) {
            //here my program behaves as if I called e.printStackTrace()
            //move file
        }
    }
}

public class MyClass {
    public void foo() {
        if(/*invalid file*/)
            throw new SaphanaException("Invalid file");
    }
}

public class SaphanaException extends RuntimeException {    //custom exception
    SaphanaException(String error) {
        super(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your code. Thanks!

Comment: If you can show us your code, and also the stack trace, someone may be able to help you.  Without your code, all anyone can do is guess why this might happen.

Comment: Run a debugger. Put a breakpoint inside your catch block. Add a breakpoint on the exception being thrown. Verify that the exception is being thrown and caught where you think it is.

Comment: Try implementing the exception as a throwable and [printing it yourself in catch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15409284/16653700).

Comment: @JoãoDias I shared a MRE of my code... Tell e whether it helps!

Comment: @AndyThomas the stack trace gets written in the exact moment I enter the catch block

Comment: @SimoPelle - Ensure that you're using up-to-date compilations of all the classes. If you're running in Eclipse, *Project>Clean...* and rebuild. If you're running outside Eclipse, make sure you remove any leftover *.class files, and rebuild. Also ensure that you have exactly one class named SaphanaException. And check that you can reproduce the issue with this simple code.

Comment: @AndyThomas I tried to clean the project as you suggested but it didn't work at first.
Then I created a new project copy-pasting all the source files... Problem solved!
Thanks to everyone.